# Extjs grid change checkbox value from false to 0

Tags: javascript, extjs3

I am new to Extjs,I am working on extjs3.2 grid. One of my grid coloumn is booleancolumn and below is its code

```
xtype: 'booleancolumn',
                header: 'Active',
                dataIndex: 'siteStatus',
                align: 'center',
                width: 50,
                trueText: 'Yes',
                falseText: 'No',
                editor: {
                    xtype: 'checkbox',
                        }}
```

My problem is that when i update the grid then sitestaus value is passing as true or false,And i have sitestaus field in database as tinyint,So its showing error like this

```
 Incorrect integer value: 'false' for column 'SITESTATUS' at row 1
```

How to reslove this Please Help

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What kind of *store* are you using? Maybe you could define [type](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.data.Field-cfg-type) *int* on store field *siteStatus*